# How to make the cursor in draftjs editor to remain where it was when changing and receiving focus?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I created a simple editor using the example code as appears in https://learn-draftjs.now.sh/simplest-editor,
but my editor doesn't behave in the same way as the editor in that page.
The cursor always returns to the beginning of the editor when I change focus, while I want the cursor to return to the last position when I focus back to it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Editor, EditorState } from 'draft-js';

export default class DraftTutsEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editorState: EditorState.createEmpty() };
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({ editorState });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The cursor's position is part of the SelectionState. So why does it move to the beginning? And how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

```
 <Editor
        editorState={this.state.editorState}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        preserveSelectionOnBlur={true}
      />
```

Saves the selection state and when you focus back to the editor the cursor will be in the last place before the blur.